# getting dreamweaver hotspots to work in emails

Tags: html, dreamweaver

My hotspots work in any browser, when I send it in an email then the hotspots stops working.

Do I have to change something for the email?

```
<img src="images/contact_40.jpg" alt="Contact" width="712" height="194" border="0"        usemap="#Map" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<map name="Map" id="Map">
 <area shape="rect" coords="305,100,455,115" href="mailto:info@bohleonline.com?subject=Newsletter Enquiry" target="_blank" />
<area shape="rect" coords="313,117,465,133" href="http://www.bohleonline.com" target="_blank" />
</map>

  <map name="Map2" id="Map2">
<area shape="rect" coords="21,63,202,102" href="http://www.bohleonline.com/interpreting.php" target="_blank" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="15,109,203,150" href="http://www.bohleonline.com/translation.php" target="_blank" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="8,159,212,211" href="http://www.bohleonline.com/conference-equipment-hire.php" target="_blank" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="12,223,231,267" href="http://www.bohleonline.com/conference-coordination.php" target="_blank" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most email clients prevent the rendering of images for various reasons (email confirmation harvesting being one) - in your case it also seems that specific email clients (such as [GMail](http://blog.exacttarget.com/blog/email-design-9/design-tip-of-the-week-image-maps-in-email)) will prevent the linking within 'image maps' as well.  The simple solution is to use standard anchor tags that may not render but will be included within the email as a broken link.

In addition, I suggest NOT using the mailto: tag as this only works if the user has an email client installed (and more importantly actually has it configured).  Point the user to your contact page that should have a server-side processed form.